# Extraction of data from arbitrary dimension nested vectors C++

Tags: c++, vector

I want to scan through elements in an arbitrary number of nested vectors. I.e.

```
template <typename T>
void scan(std::vector<std::vector<...<std::vector<T>>...>> vecs)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < vecs.size(); ++i)
      for (int j = 0; j < vecs[i].size(); ++j)
          ...
             for (int z = 0; z < vecs[i][j]...[w].size(); ++z)
                vecs[i][j]...[w][z] = (T)0;
}
```

Somehow the function can do some depth-first search on the nested vectors. Is this even possible in C++?

Comment: For recursive data-structures a recursive function usually works best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a helper type trait to detect if something is iterable. This is best done with `std::void_t` as it basically can detect if an expression is valid:

```
template <typename, typename = void>
constexpr bool is_iterable = false;
 
template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_iterable<
    T,
    std::void_t< decltype(std::declval<T>().begin()),
                 decltype(std::declval<T>().end())
    >
> = true;
```

And you can apply `if constexpr` to easily make a recursive function that can choose whether to loop through or deal with a individual element.

```
template<typename T>
void scan(const T& o) {
    if constexpr (is_iterable<T>) {
        std::cout << "[";
        for (const auto& elem : o) {
            scan(elem);
        }
        std::cout << "]";
    } else {
        std::cout << o << " ";
    }
}
```

This will work on any iterable object, including C-Arrays, std::vector, std::map, std::array, etc.

This is a C++17 solution, but this can be adapted easily to SFINAE if pre-C++17, or to concepts for C++20 and beyond.

I also made a small demo here:
https://godbolt.org/z/chcY7dE3v

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use partial specialisation (I've added a lambda to make it more generic so that you don't have to write the code every time):

```
// Create a helper structure (partial specialisation only works in class/struct templates)

// Basic case: we consider we have one element
template<typename Lambda, typename T>
struct recursive_call_helper {
    static void call(const Lambda &lambda, T &value) {
        lambda(value);
    }
};

// Specialised case: when we have a vector, we iterate on it and we recurse
template<typename Lambda, typename ElementType>
struct recursive_call_helper<Lambda, std::vector<ElementType>> {
    static void call(const Lambda &lambda, std::vector<ElementType> &vector) {
        for (auto &value: vector) {
            recursive_call_helper<Lambda, ElementType>::call(lambda, value);
        }
    }
};

// Helper function to call the struct more simply
template<typename Lambda, typename T>
void recursive_call(const Lambda &lambda, T &value) {
    recursive_call_helper<Lambda, T>::call(lambda, value);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> vector{{{{2, 3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{7}}}};

    recursive_call([](auto &el) { std::cout << el << std::endl; }, vector);
    recursive_call([](auto &el) { el = 0; }, vector);
    recursive_call([](auto &el) { std::cout << el << std::endl; }, vector);
}
```

This will work starting in C++14, if you need C++11 just replace auto in the lambda by your element type.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is definitely possible in C++. One way to achieve this is to use recursion. You can write a recursive function that calls itself on each nested vector until it reaches the innermost vector, where it sets the elements to zero.

Here's an example implementation using recursion:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37JdH.png)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Just post the actual code